# Interacting with contract giving absurd price in Metamask

Tags: erc-20, metamask, etherscan, fantom

I have created a token exchange contract that works fine when interacting directly from Remix or etherscan.io , but when trying to build the app to work with the contract, it is giving absurd prices in Metamask.

Code from react app:

```
buyTokens = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let namePerson = this.state.valueName;
let ftmAmount = this.state.valueBuy;
let buyer = this.state.account;

await this.state.contractExchange.methods.buyTokens(namePerson, buyer).send({
  value: ftmAmount,
  from: buyer,
}, function(error, transactionHash){
    if (!error) {
        this.setState({succesMesajForm: 'Tokens were successfully bought!'});
        this.resetForm();
    } else {
        this.setState({eroareMesajForm: 'Tokens could not be bought!'});
    }
}
);
};
```

The information comes from a form from which I take the buyer nickname and the amount of tokens to use in the exchange.

I am surely missing something, but cannot pinpoint the exact error. This is built for the Fantom network, but also replicated in Etherscan.

Please see below the metamask transaction:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This could happen if there is some error in the network configuration. Have you double checked that?

Comment: Hello @pbsh , what do you mean by an error in the network configuration, are you referring to the details that I added in metamask ? They are the same as here: https://docs.fantom.foundation/tutorials/set-up-metamask-testnet